# Do later acts in inferno drop better gear?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does act 4 in inferno drop better gear then act 1 in inferno, or do they all drop the same loot because all the monsters are the same level (60+)?

I know in the other difficulties the loot is better but that is tied to what I think is the level of the monster. Now for inferno all the monsters would stay the same level ( I think). So would the loot stay the same?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The above information is no longer correct once [1.03](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/6457499#items) comes out. The proposed changes are:

[image: New drop rates for 1.03; Item Level: Hell Acts 3/4, Inferno Act 1, Inferno Act 2, Inferno Acts 3/4; 61: 9%, 18%, 19%, 24%; 62: 2%, 8%, 12%, 16%; 63: 0%, 2%, 4%, 8%]

The proposed changes can be found [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6262208).

Comment: The only problem is we don't know when 1.03 will come out. :)

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: As posted by Halfwarr, Inferno drop rates were changed in 1.0.3. The highest level gear can now drop from any Inferno Act, but later Acts will have a higher chance for the higher item levels.

<strike>Yes.</strike>

Even though the requirement will  be level 60 on most Inferno stuff, the actual item level will differ on different items. A higher Act will have the **possibility** of dropping higher level items than lower ones.

For instance, the **max** item level you can find in Inferno Act I is 61, while the max item level in Inferno Act II is 62. Act III and IV both have 63 as the maximum.

This is because maximum possible item level directly depends on monster level, and monsters on Inferno are higher level in the later Acts.

Comment: is there any info what the max level can be per act?

Comment: @Halfwarr There are some semi-official sources for it at least, here's a link to a dev interview that mentions those numbers: http://www.atomicmpc.com.au/Feature/299259,diablo-iii-interview---making-hardcore-hardcore-the-no-lan-issue-and-much-more.aspx